# How to prevent unnecessary re-renders when using context in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

In my app, I want to pass the global store of my application to the child components via *context*. For the sake of an example, I have created 2 child components namely `Child1` and `Child2`, and passing `increment` and `decrement` counter functions along with the corresponding counter values to them. `Child1` is responsible for incrementing `counter1` and `child2` for decrementing `counter2`. When I am invoking the increment/decrement function in the components, the other component is uselessly getting re-rendered along with the parent. How can I prevent this from happening?

Please find the above use-case [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-smbler)

Below is the code for the same,

***App.js***

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { UserContext } from './Context.js';
import Child1 from './Child1';
import Child2 from './Child2';

export default function App() {
  const [counter1, setCounter1] = useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);
  const IncrementCounter = useCallback(
    () => setCounter1((prevState) => prevState + 1),
    [setCounter1]
  );
  const DecrementCounter = useCallback(
    () => setCounter2((prevState) => prevState - 1),
    [setCounter2]
  );
  const store = {
    child1: {
      counter1,
      IncrementCounter,
    },
    child2: {
      counter2,
      DecrementCounter,
    },
  };
  console.log('App re-rendering');
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={store}>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

***Child1.js***

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './Context.js';

const Child1 = () => {
  const store = useContext(UserContext);
  const { child1 } = store;
  console.log('Child1 Re-rendering');
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Counter1 value : ${child1.counter1}`}</p>
      <button onClick={child1.IncrementCounter}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Child1);
```

***Child2.js***

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './Context.js';

const Child2 = () => {
  const store = useContext(UserContext);
  const { child2 } = store;
  console.log('Child2 Re-rendering');
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Counter2 value : ${child2.counter2}`}</p>
      <button onClick={child2.DecrementCounter}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Child2);
```

***Context.js***

```
import React from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export { UserContext };
```

Comment: You can split the context in two see: [Split up Context into state and update to improve performance (reduce renders)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66717457/split-up-context-into-state-and-update-to-improve-performance-reduce-renders) and [Avoid runnning an effect hook when Context get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543656/avoid-runnning-an-effect-hook-when-context-get-updated/66544925#66544925)